# I can not open the movie details when I click on the movie card

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, react-native

This is my code that shows popular movies from a TMDB API key. I tried different solutions but always returns the same error, that is, I do not open the details of the film when I click on the card.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';

import { Platform, StyleSheet, View, Text, ScrollView, Image } from 'react-native';
import { Card, CardItem, Icon, List } from 'native-base';

class Popular extends Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.state= {
      moviesList: []
    }
  }

  componentWillMount(){
    axios.get('https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/popular?api_key=MY_API_KEY&language=it-IT&page=1').then(response => {
      this.setState({ moviesList: response.data.results });
    });
  }

  // This is a function that open movie details
  viewDetails() {
    const url = "https://www.themoviedb.org/movie/"
    window.location.href = url
  }

  render () {
    const ImgURL = 'http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original';
    const movies = this.state.moviesList.map(movie => {
      return (
        <Card key={ movie } style={{width: 135, marginRight: 15}}>
          <CardItem cardBody button onPress={this.viewDetails}> // <-- here gives me the error by not opening the window with the details of the film
            <Image source={{uri: ImgURL + movie.poster_path}} style={{width: 135, height: 185}}/>
          </CardItem>
          <CardItem style={{flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center'}}>
           <Text>{movie.title}</Text>
          </CardItem>
        </Card>
      )
    });

    return(
      <ScrollView horizontal={true} showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}>
        { movies }
      </ScrollView>
    )
  }
}

export default Popular;
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow! I've removed the snippet since your code is not executable in the browser. I also removed a tag from the title, since there's no need for redundancy :)

Answer (score 0):

React Native has no window object so the following wont work

```
const url = "https://www.themoviedb.org/movie/"
window.location.href = url
```

If all you need is to open a url you can use WebView https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/webview. You can either navigate to a new screen or just open a modal for it.